# Typescript Factory function type inference

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics, inference

I have a generic `createFetcher` factory function that takes a `validationStrategy` and returns a `fetcher` function.
The `fetcher` function takes a `schema`. The type of the data returned by the `fetcher` is dertiermined based on the `validationStrategy` and the type of the `schema`

Here is the code I have so far:

### Edited

```
const createFetcher = <
   Key extends keyof GenSchema,
   GenSchema extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>,
>(
   validationStrategy: (schema: GenSchema, data: any) => ReturnType<GenSchema[Key]>,
) => {
   const fetcher = async <Schema extends GenSchema>(
      schema: Schema,
   ): Promise<ReturnType<Schema[Key]>> => {
      const data = await (await fetch('/')).json()
      return await validationStrategy(schema, data)
   }

   return fetcher
}

type MySchema<T = any> = { parse: (data: T) => T }

async function main() {
   const schema: MySchema<number[]> = { parse: () => [1, 2, 3] }
   
   const fetcher = createFetcher<'parse', MySchema>((schema, data) => schema.parse(data))
   const data = await fetcher(schema)
   //    ^?   number[]  ->  OK
}
```

I'd like to achieve the same result without having to pass the generic `Key` argument to the factory:

```
type MySchema<T = any> = { parse: (data: T) => T }

async function main(){
   const schema: MySchema<number[]> = { parse: () => [1, 2, 3] }

   const fetcher = createFetcher<MySchema>((schema, data) => 
   schema.parse(data))
   const data = await fetcher(schema)
   //    ^? any   -> Not ok, should be number[]
}
```

Where `validationStrategy` should be something like `type ValidationStrategy<Schema=any> = (schema: Schema, data: any) => any`

And `schema` can be any kind of object

I've been trying to solve this problem for days, any help is welcome!

Comment: Not possible since there are no points of inference in how you use `createFetcher`. You could rewrite it to take the type of the schema instead of the key used, but you cannot omit any type parameters.

Comment: @vr. isn't there a way to infer the typeof they key based on the implementation of validationStrategy?

Comment: No. There is no way TS can infer this without any help.

Comment: @vr. Thanks for your answers. I have edited my question, is there a way to make it work by hinting only the type of the schema ?

Comment: It would be fine also by hinting the type of the validationStrategy functiom I guess

Comment: You would need to curry the function since partial type inference is not supported: https://tsplay.dev/WKpEyw